# How to send async verification emails in bulk using System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation?

Tags: trigger, email, user-management, bulk, spring22

A new verification feature in the Spring '22 release is that an user will receive a verification email once per release when they instigate an email. I'm trying to use Apex to send a mass email out to those users who have unverified email addresses all at once.

UserManagement Class Apex Developer Guide documentation for sendAsyncEmailConfirmation is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm#apex_System_UserManagement_sendAsyncEmailConfirmation).

After insert of every SSO user, I am trying to send an email to a user to verify their email and it works. But its written in the guide that async emails can also be sent in bulk. But its not written how to do that. There is no other bulk method which accepts set of user ids for example.

My current code looks like this which I need to bulkify.

```apex
for(Id userId : userIds) { 
    System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation(userId, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: The _You can send email verifications in bulk_ in the doc means you can build a process that calls this method multiple times.

Comment: so calling this method in a FOR loop is ok? It will not hit the limits?

Comment: It certainly could hit the limits. You have to engineer a solution that scales based on your customer needs, this is a standard Salesforce implementation requirement.

Comment: Yes I have tested for more than 200 users and I checked the logs, it doesn't count under any limits.

Comment: If you're confident that outlier events will never happen in your org, then great.

Comment: As you suggested, I have built a process which is a apex batch to run for 50 users at a time. Because I noticed that the CPU time might reach the limit.
With batch of batch size - 50, it works perfectly fine.